# Insert between numbers using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string like this one:

`2068414199308820683392068279206867820687022068646`

I want to insert comma symbol after each seventh digit.

How can I do this?

The desired output looks like that:

```
Output
======
2068414,1993088,2068339,2068279,2068678,2068702,2068646
```

Answer (score 5):

As one of the approaches(Oracle 10g and up) you could use [regexp_replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions115.htm#sthref1608) regular expression function to get the desired result:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select '2068414199308820683392068279206867820687022068646' from dual
  3  )
  4  select rtrim(regexp_replace(col, '([[:digit:]]{7})', '\1,'), ',') as res
  5    from t1
  6  ;
```

Result:

```
res
-------------------------------------------------------
2068414,1993088,2068339,2068279,2068678,2068702,2068646
```

---

> how can i update this value to a table customer

```
update your_table_name
   set col_name = rtrim( regexp_replace( col_name 
                                        , '([[:digit:]]{7})'
                                        , '\1,')
                        , ',' )
 -- where clause if needed
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working how can i update this value to a table customer

Comment: @user2176150 You can use simple `update` statement assigning result of the `rtrim(regexp_replace())` to a c column you want to update. Answer has been updated.